# Is it possible to install siri on iphone 3gs?

Tags: ios, iphone, siri

I have an iPhone 3GS, and I want to know if it is possible to install Siri on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to install Siri. The iPhone 4S is the only iPhone that includes this system-wide functionality. You may have read about the Siri app, which is what the Siri team originally developed before their company was acquired by Apple. This app was available for older iPhohe models. However, when the iPhone 4S was released, the Siri app was discontinued. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it **is** possible, but you have to jailbreak your 3GS first. I found [this article](http://www.iphonestuffs4u.com/how-to-install-siri-on-iphone-4-3gs/) on your iPhone 4 and 3GS.

It looks like you need:

- Jail broken iOS 5 device
- OpenSSH and iFile from Cydia
- SFTP client ( CyberDuck for Mac OS X and WinSCP for Windows)
- Extracted Siri files from iPhone 4S

More info on the link.

Comment: I am a few worries for jailbreaking IOS 5, have you ever tried to jailbreaking IOS 5?

Comment: I do not own an iOS device, although I do have pretty good knowledge of it. I've been out of the loop for a bit, so I don't know if iOS 5 has been jailbroken yet.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very reputable [website](http://www.limera1n.cc/2011/12/installing-siri-on-iphone-4-significant.html), but it shows the Tweets that iPhone hacker Musclenerd posted about his findings with iOS 5.0.1. It turns out that Apple [tweaked it](http://www.limera1n.cc/2011/12/download-501-firmware-build-9a406.html), and removed the encryption used on the locations where Siri is stored (essentially meaning that it's now legal to port Siri to other devices).

Jailbreaking at the minute is [tethered](http://www.limera1n.cc/2011/12/download-redsn0w-099-b9-to-jailbreak.html), meaning you cannot reboot without losing your jailbreak (you have to re-jailbreak before you can turn it on again). (there is a [semi-tether](http://www.redmondpie.com/jailbreak-5.0.1-ios-5-semi-untethered-with-ac1dsn0w-on-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-how-to-guide/) however).

[Musclenerd on Twitter](http://twitter.com/MuscleNerd) is the best person to watch for information about Siri on anything other than the iPhone 4S. It *should* be possible in the coming weeks, or months to do such a thing.

Just watch this space.